# Curl redirect without sending the first POST

Tags: http, redirect, curl

I'm using "curl -L --post302 -request PUT --data-binary @file " to post a file to a redirected address. At the moment the redirection is not optional since it will allow for signed headers and a new destination. The GET version works well. The PUT version under a certain file size threshold works also. I need a way for the PUT to allow itself to be redirected without sending the file on the first request (to the redirectorURL) and then only send the file when the POST is redirected to a new URL. In other words, I don't want to transfer the same file twice. Is this possible? According to the RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.2) it appears that a server may send a 100 "with an undeclared wait for 100 (Continue) status, applies only to HTTP/1.1 requests without the client asking to send its payload" so what I'm asking for may be thwarted by the server. Is there a way around this with one curl call? If not, two curl calls?

Answer (score 1):

Try `curl -L -T file $URL` as the more "proper" way to PUT that file. (Often repeated by me: `-X` and `--request` should be avoided if possible, they cause misery.)

curl will use "Expect: 100" by itself in this case, but you'll also probably learn that servers widely don't care about supporting that anyway so it'll most likely still end up having to PUT twice...